# Hide Xbox 360 Tiles

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-dashboard

Is there any way to hide the tiles in the new XBOX 360S? The ones like Spotlight, Music Market Place etc. I dug through the settings but counldnt find any. I remember I could hide tiles on the old xbox, I am not sure.

There are too many tiles and its too much scrolling and too much confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't currently hide any of them except the 'Intro' one (I can't remember the name, but it has an explicit option to not show it anymore). I agree that its a bit too much at times, but Microsoft I think also is using it as a new form of advertisements as well.